# PHP session file sometimes looks like it is encrypted and I cant interpret manually

Tags: php, session

Typically when I open a php session file it looks something like this:

```
Test|b:1;JIX|s:6:"131579";httpx|s:8:"https://";
```

But I have some newer programs utilizing AJAX and UTF8 data.  These session files have content that looks like this:

```
5hN_SMt1s6BVu7_Rt3_vTE-nVniXuk2OUUoCVdv7_RrGI-mQkvdO7IAtbOKk5XO2Kb5FHtj7Jt3dSyGyBDAtt2GLo4azj3-Yl7ozlWjFBb6k7T_
```

Can anyone tell me how I can decode this outside of the php session?
I have not idea what format or encoding is being used. I had written some support programs to look into the session files and disiplay contents. Now the programs just throw an exceptions.

Linux PHP 5.6.30 server
Session save Handler:files
Serialize handler: php
Module:files

Comment: What web apps do you have running on the same server (eg wordpress, drupal, mediawiki, etc)?

Comment: No apps. Only code I have written.

Answer (score 0):

Don't touch the session files! That's a No-Go. When you need Session data, then serialize the $_SESSION Array and save the content to e.g. a mysql table called user_sessions and fetch them back if you need.

But get NEVER hands on the session files on the server!

Comment: Your off the subject of my question.